# Prepopulate a DateTimeField in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, datetime, django-rest-framework

I'm using a Django Rest Framework [Serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/). Fields allow the [initial](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#initial) parameter to be passed, which prepopulates a values in the browsable API. In the docs, the `DateField` is used as an example with an initial value of `datetime.date.today`.

I would like to prepopulate a `DateTimeField`. However, the initial value is being ignored and I see `mm/dd/yyyy, --:-- --` as a default value.

```
import datetime

class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    # DateField initial works
    my_datefield = serializers.DateField(initial=datetime.date.today)
    # DateTimeField initial does *NOT* work
    my_datetimefield = serializers.DateTimeField(initial=datetime.datetime.now)
```

[image: Browseable API, DateTimeField initial is not rendered]

Why is the initial value for a `DateTimeField` not set? How can I prepopulate the field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to properly format your datetime object:**

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    my_datetimefield = serializers.DateTimeField(
        initial=lambda: datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    )
```

In fact, the initial value *is* set. It just happens that an implicit cast to `str()` returns microseconds:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> str(now)
'2023-01-23 18:01:19.586632'
>>> now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
'2023-01-23 18:01:19'
```

If you have a look at the HTML, the implicitly casted string value is there:
[image]

However, the datepicker widget can't handle the microseconds. While the format of `str(date.today())` is fine for the UI, `str(datetime.now())` is not. Therefore, you need to return a string **without microseconds**.